# Authenticate towards GCP Bucket via running instance as service account

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, bucket

In my GCP project, I'm trying to upload a file to a bucket. The problem in the authorization.

I'm running a Node.js webserver within a managed Compute Instance.

Trying to follow the docs https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries
It leads me to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc and I think that "Google Cloud services that support attaching a service account" is what I want: Running the VM with a specified service account.

In order to do so, I pass - when building the template for the instance - the service account name as a parameter like

```
cloud beta compute instance-templates create-with-container --service-account my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

And that seems to work: When checking the properties of the instance in question it says on the instance in the section "API and identity management ": `Service account my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

I thought that would be sufficient for ADC. But obviously, it's not. I get "Access denied" when trying to access the bucket.

Missing rights of `my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com` regarding that very bucket cannot be the problem. I have created a temporary token for very service account. If I pass that token like

```
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: 'my-project',
    credentials: {
            private_key: ....<<<MY TOKEN HERE>>>,
            client_email: 'my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`',
        },
    });
```

then everything works. (However, I don't want that solution and would prefer a solution with token.)

So, what am I missing to get Application Default Credentials (ADC) done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally, the problem was missing `scopes` in the template creation.
Adding a parameter like

`--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write \`

to the `cloud beta compute instance-templates create-with-container` command solved the problem